# Java datetime format convert

Tags: java, date, timezone, date-format, simpledateformat

date here my problem:

```
String datetime = "2012-03-24 23:20:51";
```

I know that that string is in UTC timezone.
I need to convert this string to format "yyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ".

To do this I'm using following code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    inFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date inDate = inFormatter.parse(datetime);
    SimpleDateFormat outFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    outFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String output = outFormatter.format(inDate);
```

The problem is that this code is running on a server with timezone UTC+1 and the result it gave me is this:

```
output = "2012-03-24T21:20:51+0000"
```

It removes 2 hours from the initial time and puts the UTC timestamp (0000).

Can you please help me solving this?
Thank you.

Comment: I ed a server timezone-indipendent code

Comment: I can't get your code to do that... I've got a short but complete program with basically just your code, and it always gives the right value for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output format is UTC+1 then you should use that in the outformatter instead of UTC.

```
outFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+01:00"));
```

Also, if you don't want the +0000 at the end then remove the Z

```
SimpleDateFormat outFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```